# Clicking a control with modifier keys using pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

I need to click a control using modifier keys like, SHIFT, CTRL and ALT, etc. So `CTRL+ Left Click`, or `CTRL + SHIFT+ Left Click`. I haven't found a way to do that. How would a I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mouse click with keyboard modifiers could be done using `click_input()` method.

```
# Ctrl+Shift + left mouse click
ui_ctrl.click_input(button='left', pressed='control shift')
```

[The docs for click_input](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.base_wrapper.html#pywinauto.base_wrapper.BaseWrapper.click_input) missed this param values description (possible values are: `"control", "shift", "alt"` or combined by space in one string). Will update the docs soon.

If you need these modifiers for method `.type_keys()` this is described [in the keyboard module docs](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html).

Comment: Super fantastic. Thanks.